# Average probability of drawing categorical variable from differently sized populations

Tags: r, probability, categorical-data

This might be a very simple question. Suppose I have multiple populations of categorical values as well as a group of 'target' categories.
e.g.

```
set.seed(500)

pops <- list(
 val1 = c('20','20','10','90','100','30','10','20'),
 val2 = c('20','110','1400','50','40'),
 val3 = c('100','50','30')
)

target <- c('20','100','40')
```

What would be the **average** probability of drawing at **least one** of the target categories from all populations?

I can calculate the frequency distribution of each value and therefore the chance of getting a specific result.

```
# Frequency table
p <- table(pops$val1) / length(pops$val1)

# The probability of getting at least of the target values
sum(p[which(names(p) %in% target)])
# 0.5
```

Problem is that calculation is not independent of sampling size as increasing `N` obviously increases the probability that at least one of the categories is present.

Anyone has an idea how do to assess this unbiased by sample size?

Comment: Can you explain, maybe using different terms or something, what you mean by "drawing at least one of the target categories from all populations"? I don't understand what is the problem to be solved here. Btw is it just a coincidence that the target has three elements and there are three populations? Thanks for any additional info.

Comment: The problem to be solved is that I want to robustly test whether a target event (out of a list of categories) occurs in a set of populations (each with different length). It does not matter how many of the targets appear in each set if at least one is present. Challenge is that each pop has a different length and therefore calculating the flat probability won't cut it as it is biased by population size (the greater the population the higher the chance that target is present). So how to calculate this unbiased? It is a coincidence. There are 1000s of populations of differently sized length.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Is the distribution of values in each population known? Is the size of each population a given, or is it something that is observed? If it is observed, is the distribution of the size of each population known?

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
sapply(pops, function(x) {
       p <- table(x)/length(x)
      sum(p[which(names(p) %in% target)])
 })
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
stack(pops) %>%
  group_by(ind) %>% 
  mutate(n1 = n()) %>%
  group_by(values, add = TRUE) %>% 
  summarise(perc = n()/n1[1]) %>% 
  filter(values %in% target) %>% 
  summarise(perc = sum(perc))
```

Comment: That just calculates the probability across the list. Problem is still the differing sampling size. Consider a more extreme example: One list entry having length 1000, the other 100, the last 5. The chance of getting at least of the targets in the first list is by default higher owing the varying length. Question is how to account for the differing size and obtain a robust mean estimate across all